# Fade in and out a page with delay - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't manage to reload my page with jquery after the click function. the assignment is to use a click function with the a tag in the body tag. the a tag must fade and reload the same page. So the following things are needed:

• Give the page to be loaded as an argument to the onclick function. 
• Fading out itself takes 1.5 seconds. 
• After fading out, you can load a page stored in the variable url with the following command:
`window.location.href = url;`

Write the jQuery code to hide the page after loading the web page. Then you ensure that the page arrives in 1.5 seconds.

So I tried these things...

```
Function's like: $("a").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeToggle();
    $("p").fadeToggle("slow");
    $("p").fadeToggle(1500);
```

I've also tried to use fadeIn and fadeOut in the code, but it doesn't help..

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Jquery</title>
  <script>$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    newLocation = this.href;
    $('p').fadeOut('slow', newpage);
    });
    function newpage() {
    window.location.href = url;
    }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click <a href="#">here</a> to reload the page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't passing your url anywhere.

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpnecajo/1/

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  newLocation = this.href;
  $('p').fadeOut('slow', newpage(newLocation));
});

function newpage(url) {
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the snippet below

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $('p').fadeOut('slow', newpage);
    });
    function newpage() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    }
});
    </script>
    
      <p>Click <a href="#">here</a> to reload the page</p>
```